# AngularJS: Editing a "pick-one" field in a separate view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, relationship

I am developing an AngularJS 1 (+ Ionic + ui-router) single page app. Among other things, the app lets 'CRUD' employees and companies.

I am struggling with the "edit employee" page. This page shows fields for first and last name, and has a button to select the company in which the employee works. When the button is clicked, a new view is opened, listing all the existing companies. The user can then select one in order to assign it to the employee, and get back to the former screen (employee edit), which then displays (read-only) the name of the company.

My issue is that when getting back to the 'edit employee' view, its controller is reloaded, and thus the changes made to first and last names are lost, because the controller starts with loading the employee information from the database.

To summarize what happens:

1. the user opens the edit employee view
2. the edit controller loads employee data from database and populates the view
3. the user changes the first name to a new value (say from 'John' to 'Allan')
4. the user clicks the "choose company" button
5. the company list view opens, and displays the list of companies
6. the user selects a company in the list
7. the controller stores it through a service as "current company" global variable, and goes back to the edit employee view
8. the edit controller is started again, and reloads the data from the database, and repopulates the first name with John. It also reads the company global variable to display its name.
9. as a result the change to 'Allan' is lost :-(

So my question is: what is the good practice to manage this kind of editing?

Also, if you have a better way to transfer the company from the company list view, to the edit employee view, rather than using a global variable, I would appreciate.

btw, I would like not to save the employee changes prior to opening the company list, because I would like to let the user fully cancel his edits in the end.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Use a select box to let the user choose a company directly from the edit employee form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually what I did first, but I would like to add incremental search, and let the user possibly create a new company. So for GUI design reasons, I would prefer to have a separate view. Any other suggestion please?? Thanks again (btw incremental search could work with a select, but there is no good-looking Ionic widgets for that)

Comment: When leaving the edit employee page to select a company, save its state (i.e. the employee object serving as the model of the form) inside a field of a service, for example. When you come pack from the company pickup page, restore the state from what you saved in the service. Don't use a global variable to store the company. Store it in the same service, or pass it as a parameter of the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist form's state you can use a service. When edit form scope is destroyed with some unsaved changes, you just save this data to service. Inside this service you can even store it to local storage to keep data after page refresh.

But the better way is to have simple drop down on edit form. If there's too much information, you can use modals or like that.

Comment: Thanks! Question to you & JB Nizet: when the controller is loaded, how to distinguished when it is loaded the first time, or the next ones? (first time = we need to load data from database ;  next times = we need to retrieve the tmp data)

Comment: @bfredo123 Use state parameters. You could also do all this on a single state, and just show/hide the user edit section and the company choice section.

Comment: You just need to check this service. If it contains unsaved form for particular id, you use it, otherwise - request to db. But don't forget to invalidate service after submit

Comment: Many thanks again, I now have a working stuff thanks to you! just for my knowledge, what do you mean with "invaidating a service"? I guess that it enforces Angular to reload it, but how do you invalidate it?

Comment: I just meant, that if form is submitted, you should remove data about this changes from service, so next time when you edit this user, you will query database again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can deal with this situation:

1. Since you mentioned you are using Ionic insted of opening a new view to show the company list use [Ionic Modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/), This way you can deal with everything in the same Controller so no need to save the global variable
2. You can listen to ui-router's state change event and on the employee data page you can check if the from-state is company list, if so then avoid doing the api call to fetch the employee details

I would suggest using [Ionic Modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

Comment: Thank you all, I think with all these suggestions I will be able to get something working!